# How to resume after pause in jPlayer

Tags: jplayer

I am working with jPlayer 2.4.

I have used the call: player.pause() to pause the audio, this works fine.

However, there is no 'resume' or 'continue' calls, so I used the call: player.play().

But, it starts at the beginning of the song.

What is the proper way to pause and resume a song in jPlayer?

Comment: can you post the jplayer markup and the js jplayer instance?

Answer (score 2):

According to jPlayer dev guide:

> **$(id).jPlayer( "play", [Number: time] ) : jQuery**
>
> Description This
> method is used to play the media specified using jPlayer("setMedia",
> media).
>
> If necessary, the file will begin downloading.
>
> Without the time parameter, new media will play from the start. Open
> media will play from where the play-head was when previously paused
> using jPlayer("pause", [time]).

So, considere to review your code and make use of the correct jsplayer selector like `$('jquery_jplayer').jPlayer('play');`. It should do the trick.